Regex-Matching without creating unneeded array entry
A negative pattern matching creates an unused array element.
Given is a file containing lines like these:
FILE:abc LENGTH:123 AUTHOR:Bobby
FILE:xyz LENGTH:987 AUTHOR:Sabine

I need to splice this line by line into the columns but ignore the FILE column
while ($line=<>) {
        print "$line";
        foreach $element ( $line=~/(\S+)/g ) {
                print "$element\n"
        }
}

running does output:
FILE:abc LENGTH:123 AUTHOR:Bobby
FILE:abc
LENGTH:123
AUTHOR:Bobby
FILE:xyz LENGTH:987 AUTHOR:Sabine
FILE:xyz
LENGTH:987
AUTHOR:Sabine

But I need:
FILE:abc LENGTH:123 AUTHOR:Bobby
LENGTH:123
AUTHOR:Bobby
FILE:xyz LENGTH:987 AUTHOR:Sabine
LENGTH:987
AUTHOR:Sabine

I already know about negative look ahead/behind and in theory it works well, it looks something like /(?<!FILE:)(\S+)/g but for my case this isn't good enough as it has one big drawback:
It creates another array element for the foreach loop which changes the output to:
FILE:abc LENGTH:123 AUTHOR:Bobby

LENGTH:123

AUTHOR:Bobby
FILE:xyz LENGTH:987 AUTHOR:Sabine

LENGTH:987

AUTHOR:Sabine

As the position of the columns isn't stable I can not just use an array range.
So, is it even possible to create a regex with ignores the FILE column but does not create an additional array element?
Background: I am giving you an extremely simplified version of my loop, please bear with me if my problem seem trivial. Sure, I can use an additional pattern-matching to filter out the unwanted column but it would turn a lot of things upside down later in the code. Also, I consider this an interesting programming exercise.

does \b(?!FILE)(\S+:\S+) work?

Just avoid outputting lines that start with FILE:.
while ( <> ) {
   print;
   for ( split ) {
      say if !/^FILE:/;
   }
}

grep would also work
while ( <> ) {
   print;
   say for grep !/^FILE:/, split;
}

If your fields can contains spaces, replace split with split /\s+(?=\w+:)/.

This regex (?<!FILE:)(\S+) will match the first column because at the start of the string this negative lookbehind (?<!FILE:) is true as there is nothing preceding it.
You could match rule out the match with a negative lookahead, while asserting a whitespace boundary to the left:
(?<!\S)(?!FILE:)\S+

See a regex demo.
Or a bit more precise for the value that you want to match with a single colon:
(?<!\S)(?!FILE:)[^\s:]+:[^\s:]+(?!\S)

See another regex demo.

Can I suggest using hash slicing to solve your problem? It's an indirect solution, but I think it'll do what you need.
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @wanted_fields = qw ( LENGTH AUTHOR );

while (<DATA>) {
   my %row = m/(\w+):(\w+)/g;
   print Dumper \%row; #debug - shows example

   foreach my $field ( @wanted_fields ) {
     print $field, ":", $row{$field} // 'NOTFOUND',"\n"
   }
}

__DATA__
FILE:abc LENGTH:123 AUTHOR:Bobby
FILE:xyz LENGTH:987 AUTHOR:Sabine

This will select key-value pairs out of your row, using the regex and iterate using /g inserting into a hash for the current row.
Then you can print the fields in a designated order (which may be a bug not a feature, but I'll leave you to decide).
That way you're not needing to worry about discarding 'unwanted' fields.
You can also just print the values from the row using a hash slice if that's useful:
print join ( ",", @row{@wanted_fields} ),"\n";

which is a trick I often use if I'm trying to parse into an Excel type comma-separated fields. (You can print @wanted_fields as your header row in this process too)
